# Is whitespace equals to integer 0 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, whitespace

My app behaves abnormally and figured the code below is going to else statement unexpectedly.

**code**

```
if(" " != 0) {
    console.log("whitespace is not zero");
}
else {
    console.log("bar");
}
```

**Firebug output**

```
bar
```

I thought whitespace is a String and comparison against integer zero should return false like the case above but I don't know why it is going to else statement.

Could anyone explain why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In JS, `" " == 0` equals `true` with **loose/lenient** comparison, you should use **strict equality operator** `===`/`!==` instead:

```
" " !== 0
```

To get to first condition.

---

**Tests:**

```
console.log(" " == 0); // true
console.log(" " === 0); // false
```

---

**Loose Comparison Chart:**

```
""           ==   "0"           // false
0            ==   ""            // true
0            ==   "0"           // true
false        ==   "false"       // false
false        ==   "0"           // true
false        ==   undefined     // false
false        ==   null          // false
null         ==   undefined     // true
" \t\r\n"    ==   0             // true
```

**Strict Comparison Chart:**

```
""           ===   "0"           // false
0            ===   ""            // false
0            ===   "0"           // false
false        ===   "false"       // false
false        ===   "0"           // false
false        ===   undefined     // false
false        ===   null          // false
null         ===   undefined     // false
" \t\r\n"    ===   0             // false
```

(Examples by Douglas Crockford)

---

**Good Practice:**

Whenever possible, use strict equality operator because with loose equality operator, JS does **type coercion** which is a **performance** hit and doesn't always yield expected results as shown in above comparison charts.

Comment: So whenever possible means I should be even using strict comparison for comparing thing like index? ex: if(index === someString.length) I mean here I'm sure both are number though.

Comment: @masato-san: Strict compartion not only compares `value` but also `type` of both operands. So when you are sure about `type` of both, you can go ahead and this is the case mostly :)

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have told you how to solve the issue. My answer will attempt to actually explain *why* you have the issue in the first place (since that was your actual question!)

The behaviour of the `==` operator is defined in the spec as the "[abstract equality algorithm](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3)". It states (among other things) the following:

> If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the
>   comparison ToNumber(x) == y.

One of the rules of the [`ToNumber` operation on a string](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3.1) is as follows:

> The MV of StringNumericLiteral ::: StrWhiteSpace is 0...
>
> Once the exact MV for a String numeric literal has been determined, it is then rounded to a value of the Number type. If the MV is 0, then the rounded value is +0 unless the first non white space character in the String numeric literal is ‘-’, in which case the rounded value is −0.

So we are left with `+0 == 0` which fits another rule of the abstract equality algorithm:

> If x is the same Number value as y, return true.

This is the case because `0` is the same as `+0`. Even if one of the numbers was `-0` it would return true:

> If x is +0 and y is −0, return true.
>
> If x is −0 and y is +0, return
>   true.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `!=` rather than `!==`, JavaScript tries to coerce the values on either side to the same type. In this case, I think it converts both to numbers.

`" "` happens to be `0` as a number. (Try `" " * 1`. It evaluates to `0`.)

This also works with other operators like `>` or `*`. So `" " > -1` is true and `" " * 100` is `0`. This also means you can do neat stuff like `"6" * "7"` and get `42`. Unfortunately, this breaks down with `+` since it is inexplicably overloaded to do both math and string concatenation.

I personally like all of this behavior except for `+`. Others' opinions vary.

Comment: interesting fact: `" " * 1 = 0`. i'd tell this to a math teacher someday "space multiplied once is nothing" XD

Comment: @Joseph: It actually makes sense--`" "` is a string representation of nothing. If you multiply nothing (e.g. 0) by anything, you still get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

to compare with the number 0, you must use the strict comparison `===`

```
if(" " !== 0) {
    console.log("whitespace is not zero");
}
else {
    console.log("bar");
}
```

a "truth table" found here: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Answer (score 1):

**because a string with whitespaces is converted to 0**. So
To compare:

```
if(" " !== 0) {
....
```